# How to animate vector with a path in 3D

Tags: graphics3d, vector, parametric-functions

My prof asked to animate the path of the particle through a known path for visualization.  The function of the path is:

```
x=3 Sin[t]
y=5 Cos[t]
z=2 t
```

where `t` is the time and the range is `{t, 0, 2 π}`.

My approach is:

```
Curves = ParametricPlot3D[{3 Sin[t], 5 Cos[t], 2 t}, {t, 0, 2 Pi },PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}]

Animate[Show[Curves,Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large],Point[{3 Sin[t], 5 Cos[t], 2 t}]}]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Now I need to plot a vector from a specified point {1,2,3}
to the particle as the r , the vector visualization changes every time that the point moves.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you seen `Arrow[]`?